# NA and character types can't be mixed in R?

Tags: r

Here's an R oddity I just stumbled over.  If you vapply with type character(1), and the function you apply might return an NA, you get an error:

```
> vapply(1:2, function(i) if(i == 1) "1" else NA, character(1))
Error in vapply(1:2, function(i) if (i == 1) "1" else NA, character(1)) (from #1) : 
  values must be type 'character',
 but FUN(X[[2]]) result is type 'logical'
```

However, vapply will happily admit NAs into numeric-type output vectors

```
> vapply(1:2, function(i) if(i == 1) 1 else NA, numeric(1))
[1]  1 NA
```

And obviously, we can freely mix NA and character types using `c`

```
> test <- c("1", NA)
> class(test)
[1] "character"
```

So what gives? Of course, trivial work arounds exist e.g.

```
unlist(lapply(1:2, function(i) if (i==1) 1 else NA))
ifelse(1:2 == 1, 1, NA)
```

and so on.

However, it's not clear to me why R decides to error in the first case and not the second.  Is there a way to change the type signature of the vapply s.t. the first example works?

Comment: There's an NA for each type. NA is not a type unto itself. `NA` (for logical), `NA_integer_`, `NA_character_`, etc. Type `?NA` for details.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the tip!  Rather embarrassed I didn't know that.

Comment: Np, I think we've all run into that problem multiple times :) It's tempting to write `NA` when another class is needed (and I probably do it all the time).

Comment: Learned something new today :).  I posted an answer, mostly for myself when I inevitably google this in 6 months. Though if you care to I'll happily accept anything you post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Frank supplied the key insight in the comments, namely that each type has its own NA.  So, the first example can be corrected as:

```
vapply(1:2, function(i) if(i == 1) "1" else as.character(NA), character(1))
```

or equivalently:

```
vapply(1:2, function(i)  if(i == 1) "1" else NA_character_, character(1))
```

Comment: Nice. You can also do it programmatically, like `as(NA,class(x))`